# convert string to 24 hour datetime format in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, datetime-format

I am new to mysql. I need to insert the string '2014-07-10 13:33:33' into the table column which has datetime datatype.

I gave like this,

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014-07-09 23:30:00', '%Y/%m/%d %h:%m:%s');
```

But i didn't not give the result. 
How to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Minutes is `%i`, not `%m` and 24-hour format is `%H`, not `%h`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014-07-09 23:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 6):

[Shouldnt it be](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014-07-09 23:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

`%Y` for year numeric, four digits
`%m` for month numeric
`%d` for Day of the month, numeric
`%H` for 24 hours
`%i` for minutes
`%s` for seconds